# Me llamo vs. Mi Nombre

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, nombres-propios

I understand that **Me llamo** is like, `I am [name]` but so is **nombre**. So which one would be used and in what scenario? Are they both acceptable? Is one more formal than the other?

Comment: Like everyone else here has said me llamo is i call myself and mi nombre es is my name is. They are both the same exact thing but just different.

Comment: Me llamo is: My name is. Not: I am x. That would be: Soy x.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Me llamo` literally translates to `I call myself`, whereas `Mi nombre es` is `My name is`, but the two mean essentially the same.

Both phrases are acceptable. To some `Mi nombre es` can sound a bit more formal than `me llamo`. If you wanted to be more casual, you could simply say `Soy ...`.

If you are having a conversation with someone you would (most likely) use `Me llamo`. But if you were, say, leaving a voicemail to someone who doesn't know you, you may want to use `mi nombre es`.

In general, `mi nombre es` can sound serious and slightly uptight. As someone commented on SpanishDict, if someone were to introduce himself with `Mi nombre es` in a bar, one might expect him to continue with "Bond, James Bond".

Comment: I like the way you put that Diego! Thanks so much! +1

Comment: +1 for the Bond reference. Just brilliant!

Comment: +1 for this great Explaination.

Comment: Just one thing, although all that is true, I prefer saying that "me llamo" is more like a passive "I'm called". Despite not being a "direct translation", it can sound less forced than "I call myself". At least, it's more accurate for me, since you rarely actually decide your name.

Comment: So when Walter White says "say my name!" That would be "mi nombre"? Because he's explicitly talking about his name?